# order of actions from psd to html/css to backend development

Tags: web-development

I've read all related posts, but still have one question. Once my PSD is done and I send it for html/css, do I then send it straight to development, get that down, and then go back and add in the javascript for things such as slideshows, rollover/drop down navigation, etc. Or should I do the javascript during html/css and then send it all to back end developer? Confused! Please don't close my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to talk to your designer/developer. Every developer has a unique skillset; some will handle the whole build process. Others are able to deal with one or two stages only.

Typically, the sequence of events looks something like this:

1. Design is created in Photoshop/Fireworks and approved.
2. Design gets marked up in HTML and CSS.
3. Interactive front-end JavaScript elements are coded. (e.g. slideshows, drop downs)
4. Backend/CMS is added.

It's possible that one developer will handle this whole process. In situations where there's a team working on the site, you need to ask each team member what their requirements are, and what they expect to receive from you in order to complete their part of the job.